# Most efficient way to find the key of the smallest value in a dictionary from a subset of the dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, min

So given a list:

```
o = [1,2,4,6]
```

And a dictionary:

```
f = {1:10, 2:5, 3:1, 4:3, 5:7, 6:9}
```

What is the most efficient way to find the key in f that is associated with the lowest value in f where the key is also a memeber of the list o?

With the above list (o) and dictionary (f), I would be looking for key 4, while key 3 is associated with the value 1 and lower, 3 is not a member of list o.

Currently I am creating a dictionary of the subset of key pairs in want to check and then using min to get the value:

```
f_temp = dict((x,f[x]) for x in o)
current = min(f_temp, key=f_temp.get)
```

This does work but creating a new dictionary seems inefficient.

Using python 2.6 here hence the dict syntax with the dictionary comprehension.

Comment: A more efficient method might be to create a list of tuples rather than a dictionary.

Comment: In your example, every element of o is a key in f. Is this always the case?

Comment: StephenTG: what about 5 and 3 ?

Comment: @hivert 5 is in f but not o. I'm asking if there might be anything in o that is not in f.

Comment: so, in your example, what's the *answer*? 3?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath The OP specifically states that 4 is the value in the example

Comment: @hivert there will never be anything in o that is not in f.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a [dictionary view](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) with set operations to select only keys from your input sequence:

```
min(f.viewkeys() & o, key=f.get)
```

In Python 3, all you need to use is:

```
min(f.keys() & o, key=f.get)
```

as the `dict.keys()` method now returns dictionary views.

Alternatively, you could use a key function that excludes keys you don't want to include:

```
set_o = set(o)
min(f, key=lambda k: f[k] if k in set_o else float('inf'))
```

I'm using a set here to make membership tests efficient. `float('inf')` (positive infinity) is guaranteed to always test larger than any other value.

Demo:

```
>>> o = [1, 2, 4, 6]
>>> f = {1: 10, 2: 5, 3: 1, 4: 3, 5: 7, 6: 9}
>>> min(f.viewkeys() & o, key=f.get)
4
>>> set_o = set(o)
>>> min(f, key=lambda k: f[k] if k in set_o else float('inf'))
4
```

Comment: It doesn't look like a very good solution if the size of `set_o` is much smaller than the size of `f` !

Comment: @hivert: You are quite right, and I remembered dict views, which are perfect here.